# Which locus does it represent?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, locus

I want to find the following locus
$$ y=\frac{k\cdot a\cdot(a\cdot x+j)}{1+a^2\cdot x^2}$$
where $k$ and $a$ are real constants and $x$ is the real variable and $j$ is the  imaginary number.
How can I determine the locus of $y$ when $x$ vary? I am blocked. Thanks for any help

Comment: \cdot to make better multiplication symbols

Comment: @JacobClaassen Done thanks!

Comment: Are any of $k,a,x$ asssumed to be real?

Comment: there are all reals

Comment: Hint: $\;z=ax+j\,$ lies on the horizontal line $\,\operatorname{Im}(z)=1\,$, and $\,y=ka / \bar z\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Should I use the fact that the geometric inverse of a straight line is a circle?

Comment: @Javaccess Yes, that's the idea, but you need to prove it and obtain the final equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we can drop factor $k$ which is responsible for a final enlargment that we can manage at the end.

Then, let us modify notations in order to call things by their usual name:

Consider that we are looking for the locus of

$$\tag{1}z=\underbrace{\frac{a^2 \cdot t}{1+a^2\cdot t^2}}_{x}+\underbrace{\frac{a}{1+a^2\cdot t^2}}_y \cdot j$$

(the former $x$ is now called $t \in \mathbb{R}$).

It is not difficult, by taking a common denominator $2(1+a^2t^2)^2$, to see that

$$\tag{2}x^2+\left(y-\dfrac{a}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{a^2}{4}$$

which expresses the fact that the locus of $z$ is included into the circle with center $(0,\dfrac{a}{2})$, and radius $\dfrac{a}{2}$. A quick analysis shows that it is the whole circle **excepted point** $(0,0)$.

Final multiplication by $k$ yields an homothetic circle with center  $(0,\dfrac{ka}{2})$, and radius $\dfrac{ka}{2},$ deprived of a certain point.

Edit: it may have some interest to understand that this exercice has to do with the (classical) parameterization of an algebraic curve by using a sweeping line through a point of this curve. Have a look at the picture below: the sweeping line has equation $y=\dfrac{x}{ta}$ ; its 2nd point of intersection with the circle having equation (2) has coordinates :

$$\begin{cases}x & = & \frac{a^2 \cdot t}{1+a^2\cdot t^2}\\ y & = & \frac{a}{1+a^2\cdot t^2}\end{cases}$$

i.e., the expressions of $x$ and $y$ that one has in (1).

This explains in a natural way why point $(0,0)$ is not part of the locus.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've understood (in  fact, it 's a electric current locus I wanted to find) ! I did it on Geogebra too before asking my question and found a circle but I couldn't understand mathematically how to demonstrate it neither find the parameters. The only thing I don't really manage to catch is why (0,0) doesn't belong to the locus. Could you try explaining more ? (although I don't think it's so important for my needs...)

Comment: $(0,0)$ cannot be part of the locus because the only value that $y$ cannot take is $0$ (there is no value of $t$ such that $\frac{a}{1+a^2\cdot t^2}$ is zero, though it can be arbitrarily close to $0$...)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;\;y=\cfrac{k\cdot a\cdot(a\cdot x+j)}{1+a^2\cdot x^2}=\cfrac{ka}{ax-j}\,$, so $\,\cfrac{ka}{y}=ax-j\,$, then:

$$ka\left(\cfrac{1}{y}-\cfrac{1}{\overline{y}}\right)=-2j \;\iff\; 0 = y \bar y  + \frac{ka}{2j}(\bar y- y)= \left(y+\frac{ka}{2j}\right)\left(\bar y-\frac{ka}{2j}\right)-\frac{k^2a^2}{4}$$